# How can I handle a search by a dynamic set of variables in JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm making a dynamic query to pass to mysql based on which variables I'm passing are not null.

I can build the query without a problem, but I can't understand how to work on the right group of variables.

for example, in a situation where everything I pass is null I'll just have a "`SELECT * FROM mytable`", but if I'm passing `(null, int, null string, null)` or `(float, int, null, null, null)`, with a query like "`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE x=int AND...`"  I'm not sure how to work on the right combination.

I could open tons of if for every combination, but I feel the wouldn't be the right move.

Comment: From SQL perspective you can use `WHERE (x IS NULL OR x < 10) AND (y IS NULL or y='***') AND ....` type of construct.

Comment: thank you. I have to say that I have no problem on the SQL side, my affliction is on the java side, more precisely how to handle the "statement.set" in all the different cases

Comment: You do not need to handle anything - just pass all variables. If some of them are `null` your SQL will take care of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undestood it correctly you need to build a query and apply only those values in the where conditions which are not null.

You use StringBuilder to build your query, like below.

```
StringBuilder fixedQuery = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM mytable");

StringBuilder conditions = new StringBuilder();
if(myIntMember != null)
  conditions.append("x=:myIntPlaceHolder")
if(myStringMember != null)
  conditions.append(" AND y=:myStringPlaceHolder")

 ....so on 

 if(conditions.length()>0)
   fixedQuery.append(" WHERE ").append(conditions);
 //Later on just palce the named parameter value accordingly using the similar if conditions.
 //You dont have to check all permutation combinations.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it ways mentioned below:

1. dynamically build the query string based on values of vars. Like if x is not null, add its query portion:

> ```
>  String query= "select * from myTable where 1=1 ";
>     if(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(x)) //string type
>       {
>          query+=" and columnName="+x; //or add your condition
>        }
>     if(y>0) //for integer type
>        {
>           query+=" and columnName="+y;// or add your condition you need
>        }
> ```

This way you can build your entire query. **Be careful with the syntax,
spaces**

2.

as `@PM 77-1` suggested.
Suppose, let's say your variable x can be null or not null. For both cases, you can handle it this way:

```
select * from myTable where (x is null or x<10) AND (Y is null or y<=6); //just add your conditions after `or` operator
```

Comment: in the method 1.
What if the String is empty or null and the integer is greater than 0
the query would become: 
select * from myTable and columnName=<value>

This would be a wrong syntax right?

Comment: @NikhilPandit, yes, you are right. Corrected now